# Verifying if a long is a number

Tags: java, validation, long-integer

```
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter a 16 digit number");
    while (!kbd.hasNextLong()) {
        System.out.println("That's not a valid number!");
        System.out.println("Please enter a 16 digit number");
        kbd.next();
    }
    number = kbd.nextLong();
} while (number > MAX || number < MIN );
```

MAX is declared as 10000000000000000L

MIN is declared as 999999999999999L

But when I run my program and insert a 16 digit number, it outputs "Please enter a 16 digit number and Scanner prompts again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a range check: `while (number > MAX || number < MIN )` which limits the input. Try entering 999999999999999.

Comment: Nevermind, I had accidentaly reversed the values of MIN and MAX, but thank you :)